# Cardinality of set of functions with given domain and co-domain

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I am reading a book (Klein, Philip. Coding the Matrix: Linear Algebra through Computer Science Applications)and came across the following statement:

[image: Book screenshot]

I'm having trouble understanding what this means, I realize it's talking about the cardinalities, but I don't understand the "pun" and can't come up with a concrete example to illustrate this "fact".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pun is really just that - $|D^F| = |D|^{|F|}$. The reason it's "funny" is that there's really no reason to use that notation except to make things line up like that. A "pun" is usually using a word that is related to the situation but not appropriate to the use, but used anyway because it sounds like what would be appropriate (e.g., *cat-astrophe* when speaking of a feline disaster). In this case, we're using notation related to the situation which (prior to this definition) isn't actually appropriate, but *looks* like what is appropriate (i.e., playing on the visual similarity of $|D^F|$ and $|D|^{|F|}$.

As for a concrete example: let $A = \{0, 1\}$ and $B = \{a, b, c\}$. $B^A$ has nine members ($f(0)$ can be $a$, $b$, or $c$, and $f(1)$ can as well). $|B|^{|A|} = 3^2 = 9$.

Comment: Please check. I think you want  $A^B$. You should do the one with $9$ since my almost simultaneous answer does the $8$.

Comment: @EthanBolker No, $B^A$ is correct. The $A$ I provided has cardinality $2$, $B$ has cardinality $3$; if it were that $A^B$ had cardinality $9$, it would be false that $|A^B| = |A|^{|B|}$.

Comment: @Reese ok, I'm still having trouble, when you say "... has nine members (f(0) can be a, b, or c, and f(1) can as well)...." - I only count 6 possible combinations, how are you getting 9?

Comment: @JMM For ease of notation, I'll denote by $(x, y)$ the function taking $0$ to $x$ and $1$ to $y$. Then the nine functions are $(a, a)$, $(a, b)$, $(a, c)$, $(b, a)$, $(b, b)$, $(b, c)$, $(c, a)$, $(c, b)$, and $(c, c)$. Notice that the choice of $f(1)$ is independent of the choice of $f(0)$.

Comment: @Reese got it, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For an example to illustrate the fact let $F$ have three elements and $D = \{0,1\}$ two. Then each function from $F$ to $D$ assigns a $0$ or a $1$ to each element of $F$ and so essentially corresponds to a subset of $F$. There are $8 = 2^3$ of those.

I think the "pun" is the idea that you can "distribute" the absolute value operation on the left to get the expression on the right.

Answer (score 0):

For any set $A$, $|A|$ is the cardinal of the set $A$. Almost by definition, for any two sets $A,A'$ the equation $|A|=|A'|$ means that there exists a bijection $A \leftrightarrow A'$.

For any sets $F,D$, the set $D^F$ is defined to be the set of all functions with domain $F$ and range $D$. And then, like any other set, $|D^F|$ is the cardinal of the set $D^F$.

Now there's a little lemma: Given two cardinals $\alpha,\beta$, for any sets $A,A',B,B'$, if $|A|=|A'|=\alpha$ and $|B|=|B'|=\beta$ then $|A^B|=|(A')^{B'}|$. This lemma is proved by constructing a bijection $A^B \leftrightarrow (A')^{B'}$ (it's not hard to prove, try it).

Next, there's a definition: given two cardinals $\alpha,\beta$, the cardinal $\alpha^\beta$ is defined to be the cardinal of any set of the form $A^B$ where $A$ and $B$ are chosen so that $|A|=\alpha$ and $|B|=\beta$. The lemma says this is well-defined, independent of the choice of $A$ and $B$.

Finally, there's a pun: $|D^F|=|D|^{|F|}$, which is an immediate consequence of the definition, using $\alpha=|D|$ and $\beta=|F|$.